# Por que Laravel ao invés de Yii?

Tags: laravel-4, yii

Já faz um tempo que não desenvolvo efetivamente em PHP. Em minhas últimas pesquisas, cerca de dois anos atrás, não ouvi muito sobre o [Laravel](http://laravel.com/), enquanto o [Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com) liderava alguns *rankings* (incluindo o meu) do framework a ser escolhido para novos projeto.

Enfim, minha pergunta pode ser feita assim:

> Quais as razões, da forma mais objetiva possível, que levam um desenvolvedor a escolher o Laravel ao invés do Yii?

Alternativamente, as respostas podem ser para a pergunta:

> Quais as razões, da forma mais objetiva possível, que levam um desenvolvedor a **não** escolher o Yii como framework?

---

**Notas:**

1. Não estou a procura de opiniões do tipo "eu gostei mais de X do que de Y" e sim informações técnicas relevantes.
2. Não estou perguntando qual framework eu devo usar, apenas gostaria de tentar extrair dos arquitetos PHP presentes aqui as razões que os levaram a escolher o Laravel.
3. Eu sei que é difícil comparar frameworks ou qualquer software, mas deve haver alguma razão mais mais concreta e objetiva para esta escolha, <del>ou não</del>.

Comment: Esta pergunta está em uma linha tênue. Não voto para fechar porque parece passar raspando na maioria dos 6 itens em http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/

Comment: @Bacco Essa é a parte ruim. De fato tem essa questão e no SO ela seria fechada mesmo passando nos critérios do que é "subjetivo bom". Tem que considerar isso. A resposta postada até agora, por mais que se tentou não forçar a barra, é evangelização. Eu quase votei para fechar pela possibilidade de evangelização. Neste começo de site estou preferindo ver o que a comunidade acha quando eu acho que tem 51%+ de chance de ser algo apropriado para o site.

Comment: Arquitetos de software *devem* ser objetivos nas decisões, pelo menos dentro de um contexto. Como profissional, se o seu chefe lhe perguntar porque você usou o framework X ao invés do Y, você deve ser capaz de respondê-lo em termos de produtividade, custo ou qualidade, mesmo que a resposta não seja uma verdade eterna e absoluta. O problema começa quando você tenta responder uma pergunta como esta olhando somente para a experiência pessoal e, pior, sem ter experimentado ambas as tecnologias.

Comment: @bigown A resposta do Hernandes acabou ficando bem com cara de evangelização. Se não houver uma resposta mais objetiva em um ou dois dias e a resposta já não estiver fechada, eu mesmo voto para fechar ou peço para excluir.

Comment: Ajudaria a pergunta não abrir a porta para a evangelização se fosse colocado um texto semelhante a "*Só está qualificado para responder a pergunta quem conhece ambas tecnologias e teve a experiência avaliando seriamente o uso de uma ou outra com alguma profundidade*". Ajudaria nos itens 4 e 5 do link que passei acima.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

IMHO

A maior vantagem do Laravel sobre o Yii está na curva de aprendizado.
Laravel é um framework muito mais simples de aprender, apesar de conter todos os recursos comuns a qualquer projeto WEB.
Também, Laravel possui uma documentação mais amigável e clara do que a do Yii.
Esses dois fatores já conseguem alavancar uma boa parcela de comunidade para o Laravel, o que significa ter mais gente para te ajudar, mais tutoriais, mais gente contribuindo com o framework ou bibliotecas/plugins.

Numa segunda perspectiva está o fato do Laravel ter sido desenvolvido como um "meta framework".
Utilizando-se do Composer, ele possui algumas bibliotecas próprias, as Illuminate, e utiliza-se de muitas bibliotecas da comunidade, como as bibliotecas do Symfony, por exemplo.
Assim, podemos desacoplar as partes que desejamos do Laravel ou até utilizar outras bibliotecas de nossa escolha.
Também, como há a utilização de bibliotecas de terceiros, cabe aos terceios a manutenção, dando ao Laravel um ciclo de atualizações/bugfix mais rápido.

Comment: Esta resposta me esclarece algo muito importante. Sobre a curva de aprendizado, eu realmente "briguei" alguns dias com a documentação do Yii no início. Além disso, utilizar um sistema de gerenciamento de dependências (bibliotecas) que não seja exclusivo do framework ([*not invented here*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_invented_here)) realmente vai ajudar a comunidade a não ficar criando *novamente* inúmeras extensões que sempre vão ficar um pouco desatualizadas.

Comment: Concordo com o @FReNeTiC em relação a curva de aprendizado. Utilizei o Yii em uns poucos projetos, a flexibilidade que ele proporcionava em relação aos frameworks disponíveis na época era muito superior. No entanto, era como aprender a dirigir um carro com cambio automático depois de uma vida inteira digirindo um carro manual. Você sabia o que podia fazer, conhecia o potencial, mas não sabia como implementar. Me peguei gastando horas tentando descobrir com fazer coisas muito simples, por não ter um exemplo sequer. É claro que a documentação do Yii melhorou muito, mas o Laravel é a bola da vez.

Answer (score 3):

Não conheço o Yii muito bem, apenas uma olhada ou outro no código, porém vou citar aqui os pontos positivos que geralmente são decisivos na escolha do Laravel.

- **Sintaxe elegante** - A sintaxe do Laravel é bonita e expressiva, segue um pouco da filosofia de sintaxe do Ruby, em que o código deve se aproximar um pouco da linguagem escrita.
- **Princípios sólidos de orientação a objetos** - Recursos modernos como gerenciamento de pacotes e dependências via `composer`, IoC dentre outros fazer o Framework ser moderno, robusto e fácil de manter.
- **Comunidade Incrível** - Você pode obter ajuda sobre o Laravel em diversos canais como Fóruns, Documentação e comunidades como essa. Se você se juntar agora ao canal #laravel no irc poderá obter ajuda praticamente instantânea sobre qualquer aspecto do Framework.
- **Recursos de Aprendizado Abundantes** - Você encontrará dezenas de e-books escritos recentemente sobre Laravel, com as mais diferentes abordagens de aprendizado, você pode ainda contar com recursos como [Laracasts](https://laracasts.com), que é um portal especializado em ensinar sobre o mundo Laravel.
- **Constante aprimoramento** - O Laravel é atualizado com frequência absurda, trazendo novos *patches* e recursos.
- **Curva de aprendizado** - A Curva de aprendizado é muito pequena comparada a outros frameworks de grande porte, como Symfony ou Zend Framework, basta brincar por uma hora na documentação do Laravel e você não irá mais querer largar.

Você pode encontrar uma visão geral do por quê o Laravel está sendo tão adotado [nesse link](https://tutsplus.com/tutorial/why-laravel-is-taking-the-php-community-by-storm/), que foi escrito ainda na versão 3 mas continua válido como ponto inicial.

Comment: "sintaxe bonita", "recursos modernos", "ajuda instantânea", "frequencia absurda", "você não irá mais querer largar"... parece texto publicitário.

Comment: Talvez não seja uma comparação justa quando não há os dois pontos (um lado e outro). Eu acho o Laravel melhor, simplesmente porque achei algumas coisas do `Yii` meio esquisitas

Answer (score -2):

Tenho experiência com ambos os frameworks.
Sendo assim elejo o Yii, mesmo após 7 anos da pergunta ter sido feita.

A coleção de widgets do Yii facilitam muito a vida ao desenvolver sistemas, principalmente monolíticos. Mas é bom lembrar que a modularização do Yii permite um alto poder de escalabilidade.
Acredito que o Yii fica devendo em poucos quesitos em relação ao Laravel, como o router e blade (que é padrão do Laravel).

Enfim, para desenvolver grandes sistemas com o PHP o Yii é disparado um dos melhores frameworks do mundo.

Answer (score -3):

Eu sinceramente gosto de ambos os frameworks.
Prefiro usar o Laravel em projetos medianos, como sites e portais.
Mas quando o assunto é projeto grande, como grandes sistemas, aí vamos de Yii!
Ok, o Laravel tem o Eloquent, mas não dá para comparar com o Active Record do Yii que é muito mais completo.

O Laravel é mais elegante sem dúvida, mas o Yii é muito mais completo.

Comment: Faltam os parametro técnicos das tecnologias, elegante em que sentido, baseado em que? Completo em que sentido, baseado em que?